# DIV mysteriously being placed behind other DIVs?

Tags: html, css

sorry for the probably dumb question...

My footer div is being placed behind the divs recentWinnersContainer and recentWinnersMapContainer, even though it should be underneath them.

Here is my jsFiddle and code.

http://jsfiddle.net/gjtd8tw7/

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mainContainer">

  <div id="navContainer">
    <div id="logoImgContainer">
      <img src="logo.png">
    </div>
    <p id="navLinks">Prizes Winners FAQ Contact Us</p>
  </div>

  <div id="slideShowContainer">
    <img src="slide1.jpg">
  </div>

  <div id="offersContainer">
    <div class="offersArrowImg">
      <img src="leftOffersArrow.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="offerContainer">
      <img class="offerImg" src="offer1.jpg">
      <div class="offerBtn">Offer Name</div>
    </div>
    <div class="offerContainer">
      <img class="offerImg" src="offer2.jpg">
      <div class="offerBtn">Offer Name</div>
    </div>
    <div class="offerContainer">
      <img class="offerImg" src="offer3.jpg">
      <div class="offerBtn">Offer Name</div>
    </div>
    <div class="offerContainer">
      <img class="offerImg" src="offer4.jpg">
      <div class="offerBtn">Offer Name</div>
    </div>
    <div class="offersArrowImg">
      <img src="rightOffersArrow.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="recentWinnersHeadlineContainer">
    <p id="recentWinnersHeadline">Recent Winners</p>
  </div>

  <div id="recentWinnersContainer">
    <div class="recentWinnerContainer">
      <div class="recentWinnerImg"><img src="recentWinner3.jpg"></div>
      <p class="recentWinnerName">Firstname Lastname</p> entered to win a <p class="recentWinnerPrizeName">Prize Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="recentWinnerContainer">
      <div class="recentWinnerImg"><img src="recentWinner3.jpg"></div>
      <p class="recentWinnerName">Firstname Lastname</p> entered to win a <p class="recentWinnerPrizeName">Prize Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="recentWinnerContainer">
      <div class="recentWinnerImg"><img src="recentWinner3.jpg"></div>
      <p class="recentWinnerName">Firstname Lastname</p> entered to win a <p class="recentWinnerPrizeName">Prize Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="recentWinnerContainer">
      <div class="recentWinnerImg"><img src="recentWinner3.jpg"></div>
      <p class="recentWinnerName">Firstname Lastname</p> entered to win a <p class="recentWinnerPrizeName">Prize Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="recentWinnerContainer">
      <div class="recentWinnerImg"><img src="recentWinner3.jpg"></div>
      <p class="recentWinnerName">Firstname Lastname</p> entered to win a <p class="recentWinnerPrizeName">Prize Name</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="recentWinnersMapContainer">
    Map
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    Footer
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

#mainContainer {
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

#navContainer {
width:1000px;
height:75px;
background-color:#3299bb;
}

#logoImgContainer {
float:left;
margin:13px 0px 0px 20px;
}

#navLinks {
float:right;
margin: 15px 20px 0 0;
font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
font-size:30px;
color:#ffffff;
}

#slideShowContainer {
width:1000px;
height:380px;
background-color:#000000;
}

#offersContainer {
width:1000px;
height:188px;
background-color:blue;
}

.offerContainer {
width:227px;
height:188px;
float:left;
background-color:red;
}

#offerImg {
width:227px;
height:146px;
}

.offersArrowImg {
float:left;
}

#recentWinnersHeadlineContainer {
width:1000px;
height:60px;
background-color:#ff9900;
}

#recentWinnersContainer {
width:495px;
height:320px;
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
background-color:yellow;
}

#recentWinnersHeadline {

}

.recentWinnerContainer {
height:50px;
}

.recentWinnerImg {
display:inline-block;
}

.recentWinnerName {
display:inline-block;
}

.recentWinnerPrizeName {
display:inline-block;
}

#recentWinnersMapContainer {
width:495px;
height:320px;
float:left;
background-color:green;
}

#footer {
width:1000px;
height:60px;
background-color:grey;
}
```

Comment: Btw I tried making the footers position absolute, and using clear on the 2 divs that are overlapping my footer.  Neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `#footer` in your css file to this:

```
#footer {
    width:1000px;
    height:60px;
    background-color:grey;
    <!-- I ADDED THESE TWO LINES TO YOUR #FOOTER SELECTOR -->
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :)  Will mark this as the answer when it lets me.

/carltondance

Btw, mind telling me why the position needs to be fixed?  I did try absolute, it just put the footer ontop of the other divs instead of behind or underneath.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @DavidStampher No worries, glad to help! Im not exactly sure why, I even looked at your code again and tried diffrent things. But that seemed to work for me. Im sorry if I couldnt answer your question about why it need to be fixed, im new to web programming. Ive only been doing this for almost 3 weeks. :)